# How to make background image fit to full width div in materialize CSS

Tags: css, materialize

trying to make background image to cover whole div in materialize CSS, but after many changes, can't understand why is not doing it.

If i add a solid background, works great, but adding url image and fit size to cover, can't make it work.

My code works in css, not is inside a container or row..

```css
.whatWeDo{
background:url("https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C561BAQEe01Ads5I8Mg/company-background_10000/0/1579701573454?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=TSO-iYlwaBA5aoAI3KLAJejMasD77_sYSqP0wQviok0") no-repeat center center scroll;
    background-size:cover;
    height: 500px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="whatWeDo ">
   
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your picture size is **1128 * 191px**, And you gave your div a height of **500px**, and use **background-size: cover** for it.
When you do this. It zooms in on the image so that it eventually covers the entire div.
So, we suggest you consider an image with the right size for this.

Comment: Thank you Farhad for your answer. The URL that I add in the question for image is not the same that I have in my website, is just an example. Because doesn't matter the image size, with cover should fill the whole div. So still don't understand why it doesn't work...